# autocompleteinput of bokeh not working fine

Tags: autocomplete, bokeh

i just created a autocompleteinput widget in my bokeh application.I am stuck with two issues,

- auto completion is working for the first word only, not for the rest
- i cant use arrow keys to navigate through the suggestion list and list 
  items are not clickable

  from bokeh.plotting import show, output_notebook, output_file
  from bokeh.models.widgets import AutocompleteInput

  output_notebook()

  input_widget = AutocompleteInput(completions=['pok', 'wer', 'foo', 'bar', 'baz'], title='test')

  show(input_widget)

Answer (score 0):

Please upgrade to the latest Bokeh version 1.0.4 and the auto-completion should work for all words. Unfortunately Bokeh doesn't support keyboard events so you need to click on a word to select it.